# Find out how many threads running a Function at the same time

Tags: java

I have a multithreaded application and a class function which should be run by maximum one thread at a time.

This should be the case by my application design, without synchronized.

But i get some random erros which point at the case that two threads running the same time in the function of the instance.

Is there a way to throw an exception in this case for debugging purposes?

I i could find the second thread with a semaphore, but how can i determine the first?

Comment: Shouldn't you **design** your application to be thread safe in the first place?

Comment: Thats my target, i'm trying to find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a breakpoint for a semaphore:

```
if (s.availablePermits() < 1) {
    System.out.println("Second");
}
```

This should stop on the second thread, now i activated **suspendVM** in eclipse debug settings, now i can inspect all threads at this time